# Инжект строки из проперти

Tags: spring, spring-boot

В проекте на spring boot возможно ли сделать инжект строки из проперти в message аннотации? Или как я понимаю, инжект возможен только в поле.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransferInfoDtoIn {
=    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{16}$",
            message = "Invalid number")
    private String cardFromNumber;
...
}
```

Чтобы получилось так:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransferInfoDtoIn {
=    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{16}$",
            message = "${validation.transfer_info_dto_in.message}")
    private String cardFromNumber;
...
}
```